# how send an object from view to Controller AngularJS + ASP.net MVC?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, typescript

send an object with a quantity of data from the View to the Controller in ASP.net MVC and AngularJS

*VIEW*

```
var Person = {};
Person.IdPerson = 69425;
Person.Year = new Date().getFullYear();

$http.post('/API/Update_Person', { params: { Person: Person } }).then(function (response) {

});
```

*CONTROLLER*

```
public JsonResult Update_Person(ModelPerson Person)
{
    var person = (from c in db.Person where c.IdPerson == Person.IdPerson && c.Year == Person.Year select c).FirstOrDefault();

    return new JsonResult { Data = "OK", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

**more effective method than this?**

```
$http({
    method: "post",
    url: "/API/Person",
    datatype: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(Person)
}).then(function (response) {

});
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how send an object from view to Controller AngularJS + ASP.net MVC? @nico_c

Comment: You need to elaborate it better. I cant understand it

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below Approach for passing the data to API controller:

```js
var Person = {};
Person.IdPerson = 69425;
Person.Year = new Date().getFullYear();

$http.post('/API/Update_Person', Person, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                }).then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }, function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                });
```